# Adding web-notification in React app similar to Alert but Not Alert

Tags: reactjs, web, notifications

user story:

We need to alert the user when there a modification or a comment on the thing he has posted by another user.

We are new to react and we are lost in a loop about how to notify the user who is logged in on a different page (maybe his dashboard). The event is performed by another user2 where he is on a page where is commenting on the thing posted by user1.

How can we send an alert to that user1? who currently on a different page saying "there is a new comment on your post".

The issue we are thing about is: The event happens on the comment page. We can send the alert on that comment page. But how will we be able to send a notification to other users on a different page?

I know there is already present. You can take Jiira Board as an example.

Could anyone let us know how can we implement this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). Whenever a user is on a page where you'd want them to be able to get a notification, open a websocket to your server:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('https://my-server.com/socket');
```

On your server, set up the socket endpoint. Whenever one user sends a message to another, on the server, for all sockets currently opened by the *receiver*, send a socket message informing them of the new message. Eg, on the server:

```
activeSockets
  .filter(({ userId, socket }) => userId === receiverId)
  .forEach(({ socket }) => {
    socket.send('You have a new message');
  });
```

And listen for those messages on the client:

```
socket.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  if (data === 'You have a new message') {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

This is, in broad terms, the industry standard for this sort of thing; it's what Stack Exchange does. It's how many websites allow the server to send data to the client without (inelegant) polling.

Comment: We have a server approach on this application. 
We were more looking into something or npm notification component type